# Does ffmpeg has multiple hls webvtt subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, subtitle, webvtt

I am trying to use ffmpeg to generate multiple webvtt hls subtitles.But ffmpeg considering only one subtitle in the hls output.
Please let me know if ffmpeg can support multiple webvtt subtitles for hls .

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -re -i /home/gaian/Videos/small.mp4 -i /home/gaian/Videos/sample.srt -i /home/gaian/Videos/sample1.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -c:s webvtt -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*3)' -codec:v libx264 -profile:v Baseline -level 21 -preset veryfast -b:v 512k -maxrate 512k -bufsize '2*512k' -vf scale=640x360 -threads 0 -codec:a aac -b:a 64k -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 4 -hls_segment_filename /vod/GAIANGAIANAM00000359/360p/360p_%d.ts /vod/GAIANGAIANAM00000359/360p/playlist.m3u8